# How to resolve "Cannot create CMS signature for empty content" error in C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, sign, asn.1, pkcs#7

Deal All.

I am creating PKCS#7 signed message with a plain text.

My C# source is below.

```
    byte[] _SignPkcs7_Windows(byte[] Message, bool IncludeSignDate)
    {
        byte[] _ret         = new byte[0];

        try
        {
            using (var _pub = this.PublicKey.X509Certificate2)
            {
                using (RSA _rsa = PKCS8.PrivateKeyInfo.DecodeRSA(this.PrivateKey.PrivateKeyInfo.PrivateKey))
                {
                    using (var _pri = _pub.CopyWithPrivateKey(_rsa))
                    {
                        var _infoContenido          = new System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.ContentInfo(Message);
                        SignedCms _cmsFirmado       = new SignedCms(_infoContenido);

                        CmsSigner _cmssigner        = new CmsSigner(_pri);
                        if (IncludeSignDate)
                        {
                            _cmssigner.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9SigningTime(DateTime.Now));
                        }
                        _cmssigner.IncludeOption    = X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly;

                        // Sign message PKCS #7
                        _cmsFirmado.ComputeSignature(_cmssigner);
                        _ret                        = _cmsFirmado.Encode();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }

        return _ret;
    }
```

It works perfect.
But some of my Windows Application also creates PKCS#7 signed message with empty content, so the signed message's ASN.1 format looks like below.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the content to sign is empty with 0 length.

How did they sign the empty content?

When I try to sign the empty content using my C# source, it gives me "Cannot create CMS signature for
empty content" error.

It would be very appreciated if someone can give me any clue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you can get existing signed message with empty content, then try to look at it in ASN viewer.

Comment: @crypt32 The picture above is ASN viewer.